# What's it mean when a figure player is marked as "Light" or "Cool"

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

I decided to try feeding an amiibo some spirits and noticed there's a trait I'm unsure about next to the type.  The only values I can seem to make it are Light and Cool, depending on which spirit I pick.

[image: Light screenshot]
[image: Cool screenshot]

What's the difference between these? Are there other options?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These refer to the Figure Player's style or personality.

There are 25 possibilities depending on how the FP is trained and which spirits you use on it:

- *Cool* reflects a playstyle where the FP keeps its cool, being rather defensive and playing safely.
- *Light* reflects a playstyle where they will often use their projectile attack and try to rack up fast damage with minor combos and rush-down strategies.

Both *Light* and *Cool* use aerial attacks too. You can find a guide to all 25 styles [here](https://exion-vault.com/amiibo-wiki-style/).